# Firestore returns List<dynamic> instead of List<String> (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database set up with an Array of strings.
In my code I have this:

```
  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Item(
      name: map['name'],
      imageUrls: map['imageUrls'];
```

imageUrls is a List of Strings.
I googled how to handle Lists, but I think it should be able to handle it like this?
I get this error:

```
  Expected a value of type List<String>, but got one of type List<dynamic>
```

Thank you for any input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to cast map['imageUrls'] to List

```
   factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        return Item(
          name: map['name'],
          imageUrls: (map['imageUrls'] as List)?.map((item) => item as String)?.toList();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try one of the following ways to handle type conversion.

```
imageUrls: List<String>.from(map['imageUrls']),
```

```
imageUrls: (map['imageUrls'] as List).map((element) => element as String).toList(),
```

```
imageUrls: <String>[...map['imageUrls']],
```